# Reduction of an Inequality in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, inequalities

```
Reduce[
  Abs[-((4 p)/(-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 p + 4 q])^2)] +
  Abs[-((4 q)/(-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 p + 4 q])^2)] < 1 , Abs[p]]
```

It is taking lot of time. It is running. Can any one help to reduce the inequality?

Comment: There won't be a nice form. If you `Plot3D` it, you'll see that the region you seek is really rather a horrible shape. Do you have any more information about $p, q$?

Comment: I can consider p and q each having modulus less than 1.  How to get the 3Dplot ? Could you please provide me the code?

Comment: If you look in the documentation for `Plot3D`, you'll find out. `Plot3D[Abs[(4 p)/(-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 p + 4 q])^2] + Abs[(4 q)/(-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 p + 4 q])^2], {p, -5, 5}, {q, -5, 5}]` This is of course for real $p, q$ only.

Comment: But even the reduction is taking a lot of time. Is there any way to get it faster?

Comment: @belisarius $p, q$ are possibly complex, I think.

Comment: Yes, @belisarius, p and q both are complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the question seeks an expression for the modulus of `p`, it makes sense to express `p` and `q` in terms of the moduli and phases.

```
sim = Simplify[(Abs[-((4 p)/(-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 p + 4 q])^2)] + 
                Abs[-((4 q)/(-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 p + 4 q])^2)]) /. 
          {p -> pm Exp[I pp], q -> qm Exp[I qp]}, pm >= 0 && qm >= 0 && (pp | qp) ∈ Reals]
(* (4 (pm + qm))/Abs[-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 E^(I pp) pm + 4 E^(I qp) qm]]^2 *)
```

In what follows, we explore `sim <= 1` instead of the question's `sim < 1` in order to obtain solutions at the boundary, `sim == 1`, which is where most solutions seem to lie.  Although

```
Reduce[sim <= 1 && pm >= 0 && qm >= 0, pm]
```

still produced no answer, even after **19 hours**, the special case of setting `qp` to `π` did.  Some hand-holding was required, however.

```
Reduce[(sim /. {qp -> Pi}) <= 1 && 2 π > pp >= 0 && pm >= 0 && qm >= 0, pm]
```

returned unevaluated with the message

```
Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. >>
```

However,

```
Reduce[FullSimplify[Reduce[(sim /. {qp -> Pi}) <= 1 && pm >= 0 && qm >= 0, pm], 
    2 Pi > pp >= 0 && pm >= 0 && qm >= 0] && 2 Pi > pp >= 0 && pm >= 0 && qm >= 0, pm]
```

did produce a meaningful answer.

```
(* (0 <= pp < 2 π && qm >= 1/4 && pm == 0) || (pp == π && qm >= 1/4 && pm >= 0) || 
   (pp == π && ((qm > 1/4 && pm >= 0) || (0 <= qm <= 1/4 && pm >= 1/4 (1 - 4 qm)))) *)
```

Note that, except for the solution `pm == 0`, all these solutions require `pp == π`.

In summary, solutions are available for `qp -> π` and perhaps other cases.  Whether a solution can be obtained in general within several hours of computation is unknown.

Comment: Unless I made a mistake in my calculations I have the general form for $p$ and $q$ negative reals. Would you be so kind as to have a look at my (non-randomized) answer?

Answer (score 1):

Using Mathematica as a tool for investigation suggests that no solution exists for $\text{"your expression"}<1$. If this is true, one would expect `Reduce` to return `{}`, albeit after a long time.

Here is a randomized exploration of 1,000,000 pairs of complex numbers with real and imaginary parts between -1000 and 1000:

```
f[{p_, q_}] := 
   Abs[-((4 p)/(-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 p + 4 q])^2)] + 
   Abs[-((4 q)/(-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 p + 4 q])^2)];
sample = With[{n = 1000000, a = 1000},
   RandomComplex[{-a - a I, a + a I}, {n, 2}]];
data = f /@ sample;
Min[data]
Histogram[ Log@data]
```

[image]

Comment: Shall do, but probably late today or tomorrow morning.

Comment: Your two answers are very good, I believe.  I wish that I had more time to review them in detail.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find solutions to the strict inequality
$$
 \left| \frac{-4 p}{\left(\sqrt{4 p+4
   q+1}-1\right)^2}\right| + \left|
   \frac{-4 q}{\left(\sqrt{4 p+4
   q+1}-1\right)^2}\right| <1.
$$
You can simplify a bit by replacing $4p$ and $4q$ by $p$ and $q$ and removing negative signs inside `Abs`:
$$
\left| \frac{p}{\left(\sqrt{p+q+1}-1\right)^2}\right| +
\left|  \frac{q}{\left(\sqrt{p+q+1}-1\right)^2}\right|=
\frac{|p|+|q|}{\left|\sqrt{p+q+1}-1\right|^2}<1
$$
which is equivalent to
\begin{align}
|p|+|q| &< |\sqrt{p+q+1}-1|^2\\
&=(\sqrt{p+q+1}-1)\overline{(\sqrt{p+q+1}-1)}\\
&=(\sqrt{p+q+1}-1)(\overline{\sqrt{p+q+1}}-1).
\end{align}
First consider the case where $p+q+1\in \mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R_-$, then we can replace the last factor by
$$
\overline{\sqrt{p+q+1}}-1
={\sqrt{\overline {p+q+1}}}-1
={\sqrt{\overline p+\overline q+1}}-1.
$$
In this case, we ask

```
Reduce[
  Abs[p] + Abs[q] 
  < (Sqrt[p + q + 1] - 1) ( Sqrt[p\[Conjugate] + q\[Conjugate] + 1] - 1), 
  {p, q}]
(* False *)
```

If on the other hand $p+q+1\in \mathbb R_-$ then:

```
Reduce[Abs[p] + Abs[q] < (Sqrt[r] - 1)^2 
  && p + q + 1 == r && r <= 0 && r \[Element] Reals, {p, q, r}]
(* False *)
```

and we can conclude that there are no solutions.

**Non-strict version**

Following the same line we look at two cases:

```
Reduce[Abs[p] + Abs[q] <=  
(Sqrt[p + q + 1] - 1)(Sqrt[p\[Conjugate] + q\[Conjugate] + 1] - 1), {p, q}]
(* 
 (-1 < p < 0 && q == -1 - p) || 
 (p == -1 && q == 0) || (p == 0 && (q == -1 || q == 0)) 
*)
```

and

```
Reduce[Abs[p] + Abs[q] <= (Sqrt[r] - 1)^2 
   && p + q + 1 == r && r <= 0 && r \[Element] Reals, {p, q, r}]
(*
((-1 < p < 0 && q == -1 - p) || (p == -1 && q == 0) || 
  (p == 0 && q == -1)) && r == 1 + p + q
*)
```